# how to create button with Image & caption together in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, button

Hi i want to create a button which has caption (ex Category) and the Image of it in the Button too.

so we can say that button has both Caption + Image

I hav to use javascript only

Answer (score 0):

This creates button with javascript and put lable "Category" to it.

```
var btn = document.CreateElement("input");
btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
btn.setAttribute("value", "Category");

var frm = document.forms[0];
frm.appendChild(btn);
```

You can't have **Text + Image** to button as far as i know, either you can have text or image. You can specify an image for it like this though:

```
var btn = document.CreateElement("input");
btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
btn.setAttribute("value", "Category");
btn.style.backgroundImage = "url(path)"; // for image

var frm = document.forms[0];
frm.appendChild(btn);
```

....

**Other Possibility:**

If you want to apply Text + Image, then you should create an image containing both of these and specify that as background for the button.

**Update:**

If you set padding on the button to account for the width of the background image and set the background image to no-repeat you can have both.

**Suggested By Andrew in the comments below, thanks**

Comment: but it doesnt include image in the same button

Comment: i want "category"+"image" both

Comment: @Khilen: you can't have both, you will have to create an image containing both text + image so that will be one image for both. see my answer again.

Comment: if you set padding on the button to account for the width of the background image and set the background image to no-repeat you can have both.

Comment: @Andrew Neelands: hey thanks i had never tried that, i update my answer with that.

Comment: Sorry but it doent working
i have wriiten what u have suggested me but its not working

the btn.style is not defined